# Retag "phrase" as "phrases"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

Since we are already using [sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentences), the questions using [phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) should be retagged [phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases). It doesn't make sense to use the plural in a case, and the singular in the other one.

Comment: I'd like to keep the singular->plural tags all in one place if possible. Thanks for finding this one, because I don't think it's listed in the other discussion. (it's not an exact duplicate, but I don't have a way to fix the canned text :( )

Comment: I apologize; I didn't see there was a question already for the same task.

Comment: No need to apologize - the only reason I know about it is because I went through a couple hundred meta posts this morning.

Comment: I find hard to understand what the other question is asking. There is a list of tags (the first 7) for which it's clear the suggestion is to pluralize them. For the other tags listed after _For the others, I ask only that we choose a consistently singular or plural form._ it's not clear that the proposed action is. Should not the question be edited to make it clearer?

Comment: I think I was too hasty to close this - you're right that we should probably keep these proposals easy instead of lumping them all together and making them a giant project.

Comment: IMO, keeping them separate makes easier for users to show their agreement/disagreement. In the other question, I should add an answer saying for which tags I disagree; if every user disagrees for different tags, there would be an answer for every user who disagrees, which would not help to understand what the community agreement is.